# remove all between patterns

Tags: bash, sed

This is my string:

```
 ko03008:Ribosome biogenesis in eukaryotes"/kegg-bin/show_pathway?ko03013+K07936" ko03013:RNA transport"/kegg-bin/show_pathway?ko05166+K07936" ko05166:HTLV-I infection"/kegg-bin/show_pathway?ko05169+K07936" ko05169:Epstein-Barr virus infection
```

I want to remove the urls "/../.."

This was my last attempt to get it:

```
sed -e 's/\".*\"//g'
```

But the output is this:

```
ko03008:Ribosome biogenesis in eukaryotes ko05169:Epstein-Barr virus infection
```

Desired output:

```
 ko03008:Ribosome biogenesis in eukaryotes ko03013:RNA transport ko05166:HTLV-I infection ko05169:Epstein-Barr virus infection
```

I'm losing information...how can I change my sed command to achieve the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you match the strings starting with `"/` and ending with another `"`.

```
sed 's#"/[^"]*"##g' file
```

---

#### Example

```
$ sed 's#"/[^"]*"##g' <<<'ko03008:Ribosome biogenesis in eukaryotes"/kegg-bin/show_pathway?ko03013+K07936" ko03013:RNA transport"/kegg-bin/show_pathway?ko05166+K07936" ko05166:HTLV-I infection"/kegg-bin/show_pathway?ko05169+K07936" ko05169:Epstein-Barr virus infection'
ko03008:Ribosome biogenesis in eukaryotes ko03013:RNA transport ko05166:HTLV-I infection ko05169:Epstein-Barr virus infection
```

Comment: can you explain "s#" "##g"? I have been having issue with getting the FULL grasp of sed with this character...forwarding me to any documentation will be excellent (IF NEEDED)!

Comment: Hi @Xorg. Casually yesyterday I've answered the same in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27319191/understand-sed-specific-command/27319340#27319340. Let me know if there's something else I could help.

Answer (score 0):

my version
Input

```
 echo 'ko03008:Ribosome biogenesis in eukaryotes"/kegg-bin/show_pathway?ko03013+K07936" ko03013:RNA transport"/kegg-bin/show_pathway?ko05166+K07936" ko05166:HTLV-I infection"/kegg-bin/show_pathway?ko05169+K07936" ko05169:Epstein-Barr virus infection'  |sed 's/"\/[^ ]*"//g'
```

OUTPUT

```
ko03008:Ribosome biogenesis in eukaryotes ko03013:RNA transport ko05166:HTLV-I infection ko05169:Epstein-Barr virus infection
```

or

```
sed 's/"\/[^ ]*"//g' < my_file
```