# SED character after the substitute command ("s")

Tags: unix, sed

I know about `s//` type command in `sed`, however never saw using `s#`. Could someone explain what exactly this is doing?

```
% sed -e "s#SRC_DIR=.*#SRC_DIR=$PROJECT_SRC_DIR#g" -i proj.cfg
```

I understand that `-e` defines a script to execute, and the script is withing `""`, but what exactly `s#` does?

Checked http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html and gnu website, but no luck.

Comment: The command marker for `s` is most any character you want. Using something other than `/` just means you don't need to escape slashes in the contents. Common alternate delimiters are `#`, `,`, `!`, `^`, etc.

Comment: That grymoire page even talks about using alternate delimiters for `s` it just doesn't use `#` as an exmaple. It uses `:` and `|` which are also common alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

`#` is a sed delimiter like `/`. We could use `~`, `#`, `/`, `;`, etc as sed delimiters. They uses a different delimiter `#` because they don't want to escape `/` slashes.  If you use `#` as delimiter, you don't need to escape `/` forward slash. But if you use `/` as delimiter, you must need to escape `/` as `\/` or otherwise sed would consider `/` as delimiter.

Comment: Thanks Avinash and Etan, makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

From [`sed`'s manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command):

> The syntax of the s (as in substitute) command is ‘s/regexp/replacement/flags’. The / characters may be uniformly replaced by any other single character within any given s command. The / character (or whatever other character is used in its stead) can appear in the regexp or replacement only if it is preceded by a \ character.